# Setter in parent class, with some child classes that don't have the parameter

Tags: java, inheritance

I was wondering what happens if you create a parent class with an empty setter method for a certain parameter, and then create a few classes that extend said class, but not all have the parameter.
When calling the set method in a class where the parameter exists, it sets the param.
And in classes where the parameter does not exist, nothing happens, for example:

```
class Parent{
    void setParam(String param){};
}

class A extends Parent{
    String param;
    public void setParam(String param){
        this.param = param;
    }
}

class B extends Parent{
    String otherParam;
    public void setOtherParam(String param){
        this.otherParam = param;
    }
}
```

so if we create class A, up cast it to Parent, and try `setParam()`, the property `param` will be set.

```
Parent parent = new A();
parent.setParam("PARAM");

A{param='PARAM'}
```

and if we would do the same with class B and try to `setParam()` nothing would happen.

Can someone explain what is happening 'under the hood'? I would expect to get an exception since I'm trying to set a parameter that does not exist.

Comment: Calling `setParam` on instance of `B` will call the `setParam` defined in class `Parent` and it does nothing, so nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class `A` has overriden the method `setParam` of class `Parent`. Even though you assign `A` instance as `Parent` class, call on `a.setParam()` still behave as subclass `A`. That's what called "subclass polymorphism".

class `B` overrides nothing of `Parent`. So `b.setParam()` just the call b's parent's `setParam` method, and nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

In `Parent` class, `setParam()` is an empty method and calling it from any child class won't execute any line of code, unless the child class overrides it and adds a few lines of code to it.

Class `A` overrides `setParam()` and adds a line of code to it. Class `B` on the other hand doesn't override this method.
So, when `setParam()` is called on an instance of `A`, the overridden method of `A` is executed and assigns the supplied value to the member variable `param`; however, when called on an instance of `B`, the method of `Parent` is executed and nothing happens because it is empty in `Parent`.

So, nothing is happening 'under the hood' in this case.